# не работает trigger('click') на ios jquery yamaps

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, yandex-geocoding-api, jquery-mobile

Есть необходимость сделать выпадающее меню поверх меню со слоями яндекса, сделал само меню и с помощью jquery повесил события на своё меню, что бы нажатие моего меню дублировалось в элементы меню яндекса

```
$(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"]',function(e) {
  if($('#all-2-1').prop('checked')){
    if($('#m2g').parent().parent().hasClass('ymaps-2-1-79-listbox__list- 
 item_selected_no'))
      {$('#m2g').parent().trigger('click');}
    }else{
    if($('#m2g').parent().parent().hasClass('ymaps-2-1-79-listbox__list- 
 item_selected_yes'))
      {$('#m2g').parent().trigger('click');}
    }
  }
}
```

В web-версии сайта и на устройствах android всё работает, однако на iphone и ipad при нажатии ничего не происходит. Пробовал вешать alert на кнопку яндекса, нажатие проходило, однако состояние кнопки не менялось т.е. слой не появлялся.

Comment: Неправильное решение – привязывать что-либо ко внутренним классам карты Яндекс. При обновлении API номер сменится и работать сразу перестанет. Кроме того названия эти нигде не документированы и их вообще могут все наглухо поменять. Используйте документированные возможности, иначе это костыль, а не полноценное решение.

Comment: Ну и "необходимость" свою вы не описали толком. Покажите скрины или лучше пример, как оно работает, и как вы хотите сделать и зачем. Может кто что похожее уже делал и подскажет варианты.